# How to change alarm details schema on cloudwatch

Tags: cloudwatch

Hi' how can i change  alarm details schema on cloudwatch.
i have only-
Alarm Details:
- Name:
- Description:
- State Change:
- Reason for State Change: Threshold Crossed:
- Timestamp: 
- AWS Account:

I want to add more/ please help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking of adding more info onto the 'Details' tab, that can't be done.

If you want to edit the details of your existing alarm, there is a 'Modify' button above the list of the alarms which will become active when you select an alarm.